# Preg Match PHP Expression to capture an array from text within {{STRING}}

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

```
$url = offer?offer_id={{offer_category_id}}&item{{offer_title}}
```

Is there a way how I can create a php array with the text inside the {{ }} thus resulting an array similar to

```
$array[0] = 'offer_category_id'
$array[1] = 'offer_title'
```

This is what I have but its not working as wanted

```
preg_match("/{{([^\"]*)\}}/", $url , $cols);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give your values:

```
$str = 'offer?offer_id={{offer_category_id}}&item{{offer_title}}';
if ( preg_match_all('~{\s*{([^}]*)}~i', $str, $m) )
   print_r ( $m[1] );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => offer_category_id
    [1] => offer_title
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/{{([^\"}]+)\}}/", $url , $cols);
```

Comment: Great Man ! Any idea why it outputted:

Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; {{offer_category_id}}
            [1] =&gt; {{offer_title}}
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; offer_category_id
            [1] =&gt; offer_title
        )

)

Comment: What do you mean? $cols[1] will contain an array you need

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be (you might need to play with the flag to get the desired order):

```
preg_match_all("/{{([^}]+)\}}/", $url , $cols, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```